# Please help translate my Chinese seal chop (Characters identified: 詩思妮)

Tags: translation, meaning, characters, character-identification, seal

While on a recent trip to Shenzhen, China, I came across a booth selling Chinese Chops.  I had one made for me.

The artist asked me to write my name down, CECILE, and he made me this chop.  Since he didn't speak English and I don't speak Chinese, he was unable to tell me the meaning of my chop.

Please, can you translate it for me?  Thank you!!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The characters are

> 詩思妮

You can hear them [at Google translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=%E8%A9%A9%E6%80%9D%E5%A6%AE) (ignore the translation).

Comment: Need review on the left hand side of 妮, that shape has problems...

Comment: the maker did a bad job of the radical “女”. actually, all three characters are not in standard seal, or bronze script form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid let you disappointed that the words just only comes from its sound. Didn't have too much meaning, but I'll explain each of word at the below.

詩思妮 is sound like [shih sih ní]

My first time looks the name "Cecile" I'll guess that should speak like [sih sə li], its sound is very similar to "詩思妮"

But I use google to speak "Cecile" is totally different then I think. It's speak like[sə sēl]

So if really want to translate for that,  I would say that is comes from the sounds of name. And select each word to let it becomes elegant.

詩 , the place of ambition, when it in heart , is an ambition, when you speak, it becomes to poetry.

思 , wise and farsighted.

妮 , young girl.